# Conditional formatting custom formula not working in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

custom formula is:  `"=COUNTIF($B1:$B100,"month")>1."`

I tried also:

```
"=COUNTIF($B1:$B100,"month")>1"
=COUNTIF($B1:$B100,"month")>1
="COUNTIF($B1:$B100,"month")>1"
```

I know it shouldn't work but I test all that comes to my mind.

I paste this in a cell: `=COUNTIF($B1:$B100,"month")>1` and returns TRUE.
The formula is working, the conditional formatting isn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: tried also the formula without quotation marks

Comment: excel or google sheets? which version? this should work - there is nothing wrong in your logic

Comment: Good point! it's google sheets, just updated the title to clarify it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end =COUNTIF($B1:$B100,"month")>1 worked, no quotation marks. I thougth I tried it before

Comment: I had the same issue even though the official help guide on this shows it with quotes around the whole thing, maybe just a formatting choice that causes confusion.

Comment: I used your formula in a column of checkboxes to highlight the header (B1) when all boxes were TRUE. There are 6 boxes in the column so >5 worked `=countif(B2:B7,TRUE)>5` Before coming across your post I was using `=and(B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7=TRUE) ` which was kind of messy and would be dreadful for a larger range of checkboxed in the column. Great solution. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In your formula you have to omit the `>1`.
Your **Conditional Formatting formula** should be:

```
=COUNTIF($B1:$B100,"month")
```

*(The answer provided is in relation to your info. There is vital info missing from your question. I am not sure what exactly you try to achieve. Play around with the `$` sign as well as the range and see your different results. Next time **please do share a sample sheet**. As always, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.)*

Comment: conditional format responds to boolean only, =COUNTIF($B1:$B100,"month") returns a number, you MUST add >1 so the formula returns TRUE or FALSE.